# Preserve remote target when git pushing

Tags: git, deployment, push

I've got two remotes set up with git working awesomely, namely `origin` and `production`. To avoid accidentally pushing stuff to production, I would like to only push to `origin` if I only type `git push`. However, when I do `git push production` and subsequent push will push to production. I guess it has to do with the following excerpt from the git documentation.

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the  argument, branch.*.remote
>          configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is
>          missing, it defaults to origin.

How do I get around this? Ideally, when I do `git push` I would like to get an error message so that I always must specify the remote for this repo, *or* so that it never switches over to `production`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by

```
git config remote.pushDefault origin
```

Now if you omit the remote and just issue `git push`, it will push to origin and *not* to deploy. To push to another remote, e.g. *deploy*, just issue `git push deploy`. For in depth info, consult the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-remotepushDefault).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing would probably be configuring the `push.default` to `nothing` (see [git-config reference for push.default](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault)):

> nothing - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.

It will print an error if no refspec is given, i.e. no branch to push is specified. This implies that the push needs to always contain both, the remote and the branch, insuring that the remote needs to be specified explicitly.

The command to configure is:

```
git config push.default nothing
```

And an example showing the error generated:

```
$ git push
fatal: You didn't specify any refspecs to push, and push.default is "nothing".
$ git push origin
fatal: You didn't specify any refspecs to push, and push.default is "nothing".
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 2, done.
...
```

Note that you can also use HEAD instead of an explicit branch name to mean the currently checked out branch.

As this provides some safety against an accidental push, I usually configure the `push.default` to `nothing` globally (i.e. for all repos unless explicitly overridden):

```
git config --global push.default nothing
```